# jquery checkbox array validation w/ formwizard

Tags: jquery, checkbox, validation, formwizard

I'm using the formwizard plugin and I can't get a checkbox array to validate. I've got other elements on the page working, but can't get this one (not to mention this is one of 2 checkbox arrays I'll need). There must be one or more items selected. I've chopped the page down to what I hope is essential for this question.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status_checkbox[]" id="status_professional" value="status_professional">
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#infoForm").formwizard({ 
            formPluginEnabled: true,
            validationEnabled: true,
            validationOptions : {
                rules: {
                    status_checkbox: {
                        //required: "input[name='status_checkbox[]']",
                        required: "input[name='status_checkbox:checked']",
                        minlength: 1
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    status_checkbox: {
                        required: "Status field is required."
                    },
                }
            },
            focusFirstInput : true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There are 3 different checkboxes. Not sure why only one showed up. The others vary in 'id' and 'value' attributes while having the same 'name'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` needs to be they key you use in the rules, so `status_checkbox` needs to be `status_checkbox[]`, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#infoForm").formwizard({ 
        formPluginEnabled: true,
        validationEnabled: true,
        validationOptions : {
            rules: {
                "status_checkbox[]": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
                },
            },
            messages: {
                "status_checkbox[]": {
                    required: "Status field is required."
                },
            }
        },
        focusFirstInput : true,
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! I had tried something close to that except that I didn't put quotes around the property. D'oh.